# sql server - how do I select distinct locations from postal code database?

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008, distinct

I'm writing a query that needs to find distinct city/state/country locations in a postal code database that match a city name. The columns are:

```
Country, PostalCode, City, State, StateAbbr, County, CountryCode, Latitude, Longitude
```

The result set needs to include all these columns.

Using the query string: "Brooklyn" as an example, I am able to at least assign a rank to each row like this:

```
select b.*,
  (select count(*) from PostalCodes b2 
   where b.City = b2.City AND b.[State] = b2.[State] AND b.Country = b2.Country) as Rank
from PostalCodes b
where b.City LIKE 'Brooklyn%'
```

The result set has 66 rows, 14 of them are locations with a single entry in the database, so their rank is 1. The remaining 52 rows are for Brooklyn, NY, which has 52 entries in the database, and is assigned a rank of 52.

How do I get distinct rows based on the Rank, and get all the columns in the DB? I don't care which postal code is returned... I just want a single entry per city/state/country.

I'm using SQL Server 2008.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's another shot. Note that TOP 1 works because you stated you didn't care which specific row was returned first, and this will return an arbitrary row in cases where Rank > 1.

```
SELECT  X.Rank, Y.*
FROM (  SELECT  B.City, B.State, B.Country, COUNT(*) AS [Rank]
        FROM    PostalCodes B
        GROUP BY B.City, B.State, B.Country
        ) X 
JOIN (SELECT ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY City, State, Country ORDER BY City, State, Country) AS RN,
        *
        FROM Postalcodes)
    Y
ON X.City = Y.City
AND X.State = Y.State
AND X.Country = Y.Country
WHERE Y.RN = 1
```

Here's another attempt.

Note that query performance is going to be heavily dependent on the indexes available. I believe I have worked with this table before, and as provided by the vendor the indexes are not optimal for this sort of query.

```
SELECT  RNK.Rank, PC.*
FROM    Postalcodes PC
JOIN (
    SELECT  MAX(PostalCode) as PostalCode,
            City, 
            StateAbbr, 
            CountryCode, 
            Count(*) AS Rank

    FROM    Postalcodes P
    group by city, stateabbr, countrycode
    ) RNK
ON  RNK.PostalCode = PC.PostalCode
AND RNK.City        = PC.City
AND RNK.StateAbbr   = PC.StateAbbr
AND RNK.CountryCode = PC.CountryCode
```

Comment: Yeah, I wrote it without testing it. :) I should know better. Correct one coming up.

Comment: Ok, it should be fixed now.

Comment: Ok, wrote it another way which may be more efficient depending on table structure, indexes etc.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming each record with the same city/state/country combination has the same value in every other field, you can use this query (although it is a bit of a hack):

```
SELECT b.*,
       PostalCode = (SELECT TOP 1 PostalCode FROM PostalCodes b2 WHERE b.City = b2.City AND b.[State] = b2.[State] AND b.Country = b2.Country),
       StateAbbr = (SELECT TOP 1 StateAbbr FROM PostalCodes b2 WHERE b.City = b2.City AND b.[State] = b2.[State] AND b.Country = b2.Country),
       County = (SELECT TOP 1 County FROM PostalCodes b2 WHERE b.City = b2.City AND b.[State] = b2.[State] AND b.Country = b2.Country), 
       CountryCode = (SELECT TOP 1 CountryCode FROM PostalCodes b2 WHERE b.City = b2.City AND b.[State] = b2.[State] AND b.Country = b2.Country), 
       Latitude = (SELECT TOP 1 Latitude FROM PostalCodes b2 WHERE b.City = b2.City AND b.[State] = b2.[State] AND b.Country = b2.Country), 
       Longitude = (SELECT TOP 1 Longitude FROM PostalCodes b2 WHERE b.City = b2.City AND b.[State] = b2.[State] AND b.Country = b2.Country)

FROM(
SELECT DISTINCT CITY, STATE, COUNTRY
FROM PostalCodes
) b
```

The problem with your request is typically when you group by a set of fields (in your case city/state/country) you don't include any other columns. This is a way around that, although it is pretty slow and could be optimized.

Comment: Thank you, but that is not a correct assumption. PostalCode, Latitude and Longitude are all unique for each row.

Comment: @Redtopia Can you clarify? What you want is a unique list of city/state/country, AND all of the other columns? Think about the result set that would produce... Lets say a record has the three key fields Minneapolis, Minnesota, United States. If you have 17 different longitudes, how would this record look? You can't include columns that are not in the group by clause UNLESS you take only one value from those columns, like I showed above.

Comment: @Redtopia Or is this more of what you wanted?: `SELECT b.*, [RANK] = (SELECT TOP 1 COUNT(*) FROM POSTALCODES b2 WHERE b.City = b2.City AND b.[State] = b2.[State] AND b.Country = b2.Country) FROM PostalCodes b`

Comment: Maybe I need to do a SELECT TOP 1... how would I do that using my original query? I still need to query the city name.

Comment: @Redtopia Is there any way you can include an example of data, maybe a before and after your query runs? i don't think I understand your request.

Comment: Header: Country/PostalCode/City/State/StateAbbr/County/CountyCode/Latitude/Longitude/Rank, example row: 
AT/6108/Larchetalm/Tirol/T/Innsbruck-Land/703/47.40000 11.25000/NULL/1

Comment: That doesn't help sorry. Maybe...how is this wrong? `SELECT b.*, [RANK] = (SELECT TOP 1 COUNT(*) FROM POSTALCODES b2 WHERE b.City = b2.City AND b.[State] = b2.[State] AND b.Country = b2.Country) FROM PostalCodes b`

Comment: I'm happy to try it, but how would I match on City? For example, how would I find WHERE City LIKE 'Brook%'

Comment: @Redtopia Ah sorry. It would be: `SELECT b.*, [RANK] = (SELECT TOP 1 COUNT(*) FROM POSTALCODES b2 WHERE b.City = b2.City AND b.[State] = b2.[State] AND b.Country = b2.Country) FROM PostalCodes b WHERE City LIKE 'Brook%'`

Comment: That is giving me non-distinct rows on City/State/Country. Given the search string "Brook" the query needs to return a single row for Brooklyn, NY. But because there are 52 postal codes in Brooklyn, I'm getting 52 rows.

Answer (score 0):

```
select COUNT(City),City,State,Country
from
 PostalCodes
 group by City,State,Country
 order by COUNT(City)
```

Answer (score 0):

From your query, you are looking for a count of postal codes by City, State, and Country.

I think this will give you what you are looking for:

```
SELECT  B.City, B.State, B.Country, COUNT(*) AS Rank
FROM    PostalCodes B
GROUP BY B.City, B.State, B.Country
```

Comment: This is close, but my question states that I need to get all the columns back. PostalCode, Latitude, and Longitude are all unique. I'm not looking for a count... that's already been determined in my query above as Rank. I just need to tune the result set so that there's a distinct row for each city/state/country without caring about which row is returned (ie, I don't care which PostalCode, Latitude/Longitude is returned).